# Install Vulkan for Steam Proton on GTX 770M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, vulkan

I run Steam on an Ubuntu 22.
I would like to run Windows game with Proton, the tool provided by Steam.
For this, I need to have Vulkan on my computer.

My graphics card is GTX 770M, which is stuck at Nvidia driver 390.
This driver did not include Vulkan and I guess I have to install it manually.

Could you point me in the right direction for this installation?
All I can find is to update my driver, but I'm at the latest driver for my (old) graphics card.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Your real problem is that you can't install some game. I suggest that you ask about that, instead of your proposed solution.  You should tell us what game you are trying to install, details about what you've done so far, and if you have a theory about a possible path to a solution, then you should give us the details about why you think this will work.  Did you read this somewhere? DId you get an error telling you to do this, etc

Comment: Keep in mind that Windows software is not designed to run on Ubuntu. Wine and Proton are compatibility layers that provide some level of support to many applications, but because Windows apps are not like Linux apps, each application will have its own quirks and issues when you try to force it to run on an operating system it's not designed for.  This is why you should always focus on each application separately when attempting to run Windows software on Ubuntu. In order to do this, we need to know at a minimum what you're trying to install.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ran steam with the command line (using steam command) and it gave me additionnal information that led me to find that my PC does not support recent versions of Proton. By running Proton 4, I fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran steam with the command line (using steam command) and it gave me additionnal information that led me to find that my PC does not support recent versions of Proton. By running Proton 4, I fixed the issue :)